# Directly accessing a drive used as a NAS drive by a raspberry

Tags: pi-3, usb

I successfully tried to **add a NAS** to my local network. I did this using a **RaspberryPi 3**, **samba** and a **USB stick formatted in NTFS**. My RPI use *ntfs-3g driver* for accessing the drive.

My problem is that when gently turning off the raspberry and connecting the USB stick on a Windows computer Windows can't read it.

Is it suppose to work? (Or can't it)
If it is supposed to work what may be the issue?

Thanks !

PS :

The stick was formatted on windows,
plugin out the stick from the RPI to plug it in in a windows computer and then back to the raspberry doesn't break my setup.

Comment: Format the USB stick on Windows with NTFS and put a file on it. Can you read the file on the RasPi? Format the USB stick on the RasPi with NTFS and put a file on it. Can you read the file on Windows?

Comment: Formating the stick on windows with NTFS : the files are readable by both systems, even if linux says **The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
The file system wasn't safely closed on Windows. Fixing.** 

Looks like a problems solved to me, the inverse doesn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, formatting the USB stick on windows and putting files on it on windows force something to happen.

After that linux can use the stick, for the NAS and the key is readable by both systems.